# yii2 работа с jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

Добрый день! Вопрос следующий, есть сайт без перезагрузок (уже прикручен к yii2), навешано событий на ссылки, при клике на которые меняется контент и в адресной строке добавляется параметр вида "#info". Если клацать без pjax - все нормально. Но стоит использовать pjax вылетает ошибка в консоли:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /site/reload#contact
>
> Sizzle Sizzle.error() jquery.js:1468
>
> Sizzle Sizzle.tokenize() jquery.js:2125
> Sizzle Sizzle.select()jquery.js:2546
>
> Sizzle()jquery.js:869
>
> .find() jquery.js:2792
>
> jQuery.fn.init() jquery.js:2909
>
> jQuery() jquery.js:75
>
> <анонимная> script.js:91
>
> jQuery.event.dispatch() jquery.js:4736
>
> jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle() jquery.js:4549

Код:
views/layouts/test

```
<?= Html::a("Обновить", ['site/reload', '#' => 'contact'], [
    'class' => 'hire-me hire-me2 font-alt section-link',
    'id' => 'refreshButton',
]) ?>
```

views/site/test

```
<?php
    use yii\widgets\Pjax;
?>

<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'comments',
    'enablePushState' => true,
    'linkSelector' => '.section-link'
]); ?>
    <p>Начальный текст</p>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

controllers/Site/Controller

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $this->layout = "@app/views/layouts/test";
    return $this->render('test');
}

public function actionReload()
{
    $this->layout = "@app/views/layouts/test";
    return $this->renderAjax('reload');
}
```

views/site/reload

```
<h1>reload</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения, ответ крылся в другом месте... Для обработки события клика по ссылке создана функция js и там тянулся путь из href. Дело в том, что все ссылки на сайте вида:

```
<a href='#comment' class='active'>Коммент</a>
```

А при использовании

```
<?= Html::a("Reload", ['site/reload', '#' => 'contact'], [
    'class' => 'hire-me hire-me2 font-alt section-link',
    'id' => 'refreshButton',
]) ?>
```

Создаётся ссылка вида

```
<a href="/site/reload#contact">reload</a>
```

И, в итоге, обработчик получает не то что ему нужно... После отбрасывания всего, что до знака "#" стало все на свои места! Надеюсь кому-то этим помогу...